# How can I separate same column values to a variable based on value in another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose I Have below table

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | two |
| 1 | three |
| 2 | four |
| 1 | last |

for value in A=1
then I need the output as one;three;last
how can I query this in Oracle's SQL?

Comment: What do you expect to get for A = 2, then?

Answer (score 1):

If you care whether you get the string "one;three;last" or "three;one;last" or some other combination of the three values, you'd need some additional column to order the results by (a database table is inherently unordered).  If there is an `id` column that you're not showing, for example, that could do that, you'd `order by id` in the `listagg`.

If you don't care what order the values appear in the result, you could do something like this

```
select listagg( b, ';' ) within group (order by a)
  from your_table
 where a = 1
```